# How to implement 2 different views of unknown size?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

**Recycler View**

I am adding **images** from gallery and text from **edit text**.

Two arrays for getting two different views:
`private ArrayList<Bitmap> mImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
 private ArrayList<String> mDataSet = new ArrayList<String>();`

**Problem:** my getItemViewType method shows `Array out of index exception` and not getting views properly.

```
`@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(modellist1.get(position) instanceof Bitmap) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GETTING IMAGE VIEW TYPE");
            return VIEW_TYPE_FIRST;
        }
        else if (modellist2.get(position) instanceof String) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GETTING TEXT VIEW TYPE");
            return VIEW_TYPE_SECOND;
     }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to manage 2 separate list to populate a recyclerview, even if it's dynamically.
Check out this link [Multiple View types in a recyclerview](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView).

Once you add different elements in the list, the recycler view gives you a function `getItemViewType` which lets you specify what view needs to be inflated for which item.
As for adding element dynamically you can add the element to the list and let the recyclerview adapter know by using the variety of helper functions that the adapter  provides such as `notifyItemChanged`, `notifyItemRangeInserted` etc.
More at this link [Recycler View Adapter Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

About the size of the images, that doesn't really fall under the recyclerview bracket, that's based on your custom logic, either you could make the imageview  40x40 or you could make it match_parent, you have control of the view that is being inflated along with the logic for populating the inflated view.

Comment: Thank u i have a doubt.I had used 2 lists because to view  2 different types Bitmap and String.How can i use a single list?? @Jude

Comment: I'm guessing you did not go through the link that i posted, please go through that, the multiple view types, it'll give you exactly what you want, basically you'll have a function called getItemViewType() in your adapter where you can say that a particular item in the list is of type Bitmap so use the layout called item_bitmap.xml or the item is of type String so use the layout called item_string.xml

Comment: Thank you @Jude i managed my single list with 2 layouts to get two different views.Got 2 different views now thank u

Comment: You're welcome, could you make the answer as correct please if everything worked out fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (modellist.get(position).IfImage() != null) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_FIRST;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_SECOND;
        }

    }
```